# yum halts after installing 7 packages on centos container

Tags: centos, yum, lxc, containers, halt

I was curious about containers, so decided to give it a try. Prepared a server as host with a fresh install of CentOS 7, installed lxc and lxc-templates and configured a bridge interface.

I've created a centos container, everything worked fine, except for one strange behaviour: yum installed 7 packages and halted at the 8th one without error, just keeps saying Installing forever. Tried using --verbose and -d9 options, still no error, not even in the yum, dmesg and messages logs

This bug isn't present on debian containers. Does anyone have an idea or has the same issue?

Edit: if I cancel the current yum installation and run yum-complete-transaction the installation finishes without problem. Unless there's a pending count of more than 7 packages to install, in that case I have to cancel the task and run again. Always stops after the 7th package.

Comment: Have you run this in one session, then watched your disk space in another session while it installs?  Could it be that lxc is deploying files under /var and filling up the disk?

Comment: Nope @Aaron, I just have /boot /home and / partitions, currently root has 27GB of available space.

Answer (score 0):

It's [a LXC 1.0.11 bug on CentOS 7](https://www.dsfc.net/logiciel-libre/linux/centos-linux-logiciel-libre/creation-containers-lxc-centos-7/#Bogue_rencontre). When I create a Linux Container on Fedora 27 with LXC 2.0.9, I've got no bug.